# How to add clickable icon to leftmost corner of activity bar on Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, icons

I would like to know how I could create a clickable icon in the corner of the action-bar. I figured out how to add *the* app icon in the corner, but it is not clickable and it has a notable lag time after opening the app to appear.

On that point, I want to be able to place *any* icon there, not just the app icon. I would also like the icon to be *clickable* and eventually have the option of placing an activity in its place such as refreshing the page or returning to the top, much like the twitter app. I'll include a screenshot of both my app and the twitter app to give you an idea of what I'm asking for.

Picture of the twitter app with the button pressed as I want it:

[image]

Picture of my app with the activity button I added but not in the left corner:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean tried toolbar? I've used activity bar and found how to populate with buttons but I don't know how to get rid of app name and put a button in far left corner.

Comment: Did you tried tool bar instead of action bar

Comment: No I haven't. I'll try that now thanks for the advice. Hope it works.

Comment: cool, it will definitely works..

Comment: Hi. I know it's been a while but I still haven't resolved this issue. I have a toolbar and I have it populated with things. However, I still don't know how to add a button in the top left corner like on twitter. Any help? I have things on the right and each one I add in menu_main.xml adds on, but I don't know how to make one be set to the left. With getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); this command in the .java file, a back button appears in the corner. How can I make an identical looking tab but with my app icon?

Comment: did you try the below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this answers your question perfectly, but Recently I've created a custom toolbar which had buttons on the left, center and right.

Since I only had one Activity, I've put this XML in my MainActivity's layout. If you want it on top of every Activity, it might not be smart..

In Activity xml, as first element use this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main_screen_top_toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/MainToolBarTheme"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/main_screen_top_toolbar_settings"
        android:layout_height="75dip"
        android:layout_width="75dip"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_settings" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/main_screen_top_toolbar_logo"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_app" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/main_screen_top_toolbar_social"
        android:layout_height="80dip"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_social" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In style.xml - set the App theme to be NoActionBar

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
</style>

<style name="MainToolBarTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
</style>
```

In your code (.java file) - you can refer to the buttons like so:

```
ImageButton settingsButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.main_screen_top_toolbar_settings);

settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Do whatever...
        }
    });
```

Change the icons/ids of the ImageButton's to be your icons and ids.
Hope this helps, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for the attempted help but this didn't solve my problem. The imagebuttons raise red flags and when I set as items the gravity left has no effect. Wish I could get gravity working for the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

Check the below code. Hope it will work for you,

**In your XML:**
1. Add the toolbar to your layout file at the top.

```
<LinearLayout> 
......
......
...  
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 android:id = "@+id/toolbar"
 xmlns:local = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width = "match_parent"
 android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
 android:background = "@color/colorPrimary"
 android:minHeight = "?attr/actionBarSize"
 local:popupTheme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
 local:theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

..... 
.........
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your Activity write the below code in `onCreate`. Make sure you extends **AppCompat Activity**.

```
Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
  toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);  // Replace with your icon
}
```

In your **style.xml**, add the following code to your app theme,

```
<item name = "windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name = "windowActionBar">false</item>
```

This will definitely works. Try.. 
Happy coding..!!

Comment: This worked like a charm minus two things. One, I'm not sure how to resize the icon within android studio, I have to edit it in my paint program to a very small size for it to shrink, and 2, how can I assign an action to this button? Thanks!

Comment: This is another question for me. :)

Comment: This is the easiest solution when using a Toolbar. 
Add the action handling with  `setNavigationOnClickListener` and ensure to also provide `setNavigationContentDescription`